# Is there any way to find which action/hook is fired?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using woocommerce subscription and I'm trying to find out which action is fired when there is a new subscription or upgrades/downgrades on an existing one so I can update an external db.

Comment: If you have a question about the inner workings of a third party plugin/theme, you have a better chance of getting an answer at its author's forum

Comment: @cjbj is correct about your specific question.  To generalize your question, the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin allows you to see which hooks fire for _any_ given request, and would probably help in your specific case if you can't get an answer from woocommerce's support.

Answer (score 4):

Try [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) which will show you which actions get fired on a given page.

Comment: ha!  I just recommended the same thing in a comment to the question :-)

Comment: I saw that! Great minds think alike :) Looks like a very good plugin (I've used wp debug bar before and I don't love it).